# How can I schedule notifications and database modification in firebase

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an iOS app using firebase and swift. I have two database node, one containing active records and another containing inactive records.

I want to schedule a task such that every day at 10 Am a record from inactive records node is transferred to active records node and send all my app user a push notification regarding that.

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried using Javascript for the same and later realised that javascript is not the right tool fro the same as it require client browser to be opened at that particular time.

Comment: Later I tried using javascript in php script and scheduling it using cron job on digital ocean VPS, but didn't get expected output as script didn't work. @TomášHübelbauer